# Using Flutter path_provider to find a txt file stored with previous version of app built with Adobe AIR

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have an existing Android/iOS app built using Adobe AIR. I'm rebuilding it from scratch using Flutter. So far so good, but I need to access a text file — stored on device — that stores the user's ID. The file path in Adobe AIR is:

\appName\Local Store\userID.txt

I'm looking for a way to read that data in my Flutter app. (Currently using path_provider plugin.) Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Every attempt I made to directly access the file(s) failed. Of course Adobe AIR and Flutter use the same sandbox to store local files, but the file structure within the sandbox is different.

My solution was to use `file.listSync( recursive: true );`

I don't know exactly where the files are, but I know they're in this sandbox somewhere so a recursive search should work and it did.

I start by getting the applictaionDocumentsDirectory, but that isn't the root of the sandbox. To get the root I create a substring of the `directory.path.lastIndexOf( '/' )`.

Then recursively look through all the files/folders for userID.txt and tempID.txt.

If the files are found then the contents are stored in static ints on my Init class. Once both values are set the loop exits.

It's not the most elegant solution, but the only one I found that was foolproof. And since this saves existing users from the need of logging in again, and all the hassle of supporting 200k people trying to remember which email address they used, it's worth it.

Note: in my case this code only needs to run one time, the first time the app is run after install.

```
getPreviousUserIDs() async {
        dynamic directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        String path = directory.path.substring( 0, directory.path.lastIndexOf( '/' ) );
        dynamic file = io.Directory( path );
        
        List allContents = file.listSync( recursive: true );
        for ( var fileOrDir in allContents ) {
            if ( fileOrDir is io.File ) {
                
                if( fileOrDir.path.indexOf( 'userID.txt' ) > 0 ) {
            
                    // Set static value on Init.
                    Init.userID = int.parse( await fileOrDir.readAsString() );
                    
                } else if( fileOrDir.path.indexOf( 'tempID.txt' ) > 0 ) {
                    
                    // Set static value on Init.
                    Init.tempID = int.parse( await fileOrDir.readAsString() );
                    
                }
                
                if(     Init.userID != null
                    &&  Init.tempID != null )
                    break;
                
            }
        }
    }
```